# Why does file creation fail in Application_Start?

Tags: asp.net

I have some code which attempts to create and write to a log file in a subdirectory of my website (shown below).  If I put the first call to this code in the **Page_Load()** event of **Default.aspx**, it works fine every time.  If, however, I make the first call to this code inside the **Global.asax Application_Start()** event, I get an access denied exception from .NET IO library, even though the path displayed in the exception message is correct.

Has anyone encountered anything like this?  It is as if the code running from **Application_Start()** has a more limited set of permissions than code running later.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

```
using( StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( FullPathAndNameData, true ) )
{
    string logEntry = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + formattedMessage;
    writer.WriteLine( logEntry );
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `Application_Start` doesn't have special permission.

Only thing I can think of is if you move the code inside `Application_Start`, the file path is moved outside of Web Application and it needs permission.

You can try using `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fullPathAndNameData = string.Format("{0}App_Data\\Log.txt",
            HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fullPathAndNameData, true))
        {
            string logEntry = DateTime.Now + ": " + "Inside Application_Start";
            writer.WriteLine(logEntry);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  Unfortunately, the behaviour is exactly the same.  It really does seem that the application doesn't have the same permissions inside Application_Start().

Comment: I tested the above code in local machine, and it works fine. It might be that you have `Write Permission` issue in our hosted site.

Comment: I can consistently create/write a file in a subdir from the Page_Load of Default.aspx.  The same code always fails in Application_Start, even if the file already exists and has been written from Page_Load.  I have been through this with a good tech guy at my hosting provider, and the only way he can get it to work is by adding network write permission to the folder, which means anyone can write to it.  It really does seem that permissions in Application_Start are not the same as later (e.g. Page_Load).  I can't find info on this problem anywhere.  Has anyone encountered anything like this?

Comment: Could you please upload the exception message?